# IOMutable vs MutableIO File

Tags: frege

I am trying to load a file.

I have:

```
wf :: STMutable a File
wf = File.new "worlds/seed_77.world"

data PickleSerialization = pure native com.github.lands.PickleSerialization where
native loadWorld com.github.lands.PickleSerialization.loadWorld :: MutableIO File -> IO World throws IOException, IncorrectFileException
```

If I try to do:

```
PickleSerialization.loadWorld wf
```

I get this error, which seems very confusing to me:

```
[ERROR: 4]: type error in  expression wf
type is   IOMutable File
used as   MutableIO File
```

Comment: Arguably, the type checker has a sense of humor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wf` returns an action that produces a file. `loadWorld` takes a file, not an action. I think this should work: `wf >>= loadWorld`.

`MutableIO File` represents a mutable file whereas `IOMutable` is an action that returns a mutable file. `IOMutable` is defined as (taken from the source):

`--- This is an abbreviation for @ST RealWorld (Mutable RealWorld d)@ 
type IOMutable d = IO (MutableIO d)`

Similarly `STMutable` is defined as,

`--- The type of 'ST' actions that return a mutable value of type _d_
--- This is an abbreviation for @ST s (Mutable s d)@ 
type STMutable s d = ST s (Mutable s d)`

Comment: Excellent explanation, as always. Adding to it the following: the confusion arises also because `type IO = ST RealWorld`. Now, in type checking, all type aliases are already expanded. But on output (like in an error message), the system tries to un-expand types, so as to give the user something familiar. Hence `ST RealWorld (Mutable RealWorld File)` becomes after some iterations `IOMutable File`

Comment: But in this case, this unexpanding was counter-productive, cause Frederico had it quite correct, and when the error message told him: I need a `MutableIO File`, but have a `STMutable RealWorld File` he would certainly have found out. This is the weakness, it also shines up if you have `type Number=Int`  and `type Cardinal=Int` Which un-expansion to choose? It's arbitrary.